# Sharepoint 2013 Hosted Add-in using React and React router

Tags: sharepoint-addin, visual-studio, react

I have a reach JS app that uses react router. As a stand alone it works perfectly. I am now trying to use it in a SharePoint hosted app. I created the app using create-react-app from github. When I build it and copy the resultant .js and .css file to the SharePoint script folder in my (Visual Studio 2015) SharePoint hosted add-in project, and run it, I get "react-empty: 1" in the root div. I suspect this has to do with react router because I when I disabled routing and had a direct reference to my start component, it worked.

Has anyone gotten react routing working in a SharePoint hosted app?

Comment: We do use react-router in a SharePoint hosted app and it seems to work just fine. How do you reference the JS and the CSS files from the SharePoint page?